# Grouping data based on users initial uitableview input

Tags: ios, core-data

I am looking into what method I should be looking at to link the users intial input with the following selected rows.

Currently I am adding excercises to the coredata entity when they are clicked as in below:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is for the excercises to be added to the routine named in the previous uitableview. This involves the user naming the routine group ('routinename' in core data entity), for example "4 Day Workout" which is added to the intial core data entity. The following excercises are added to the entity detail with a relationship based on the routine group.

[image]

I have created the relationships in the core data model on a 1 to many relationship:

[image]

I am adding it to the entity currently using :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"Added to Routine!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new device
    ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue: info.name  forKey:@"routinename"];

    NSManagedObject *newDevice1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutinesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice1 setValue: info.name  forKey:@"name"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Display Alert Message
    [messageAlert show];

    //Update with checkmark
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Basically I am looking at what method I should be looking into to achieve this and any suggestions in regards to the code.

My routineDetailViewController has the following on the 'button'

```
- (IBAction)SaveButton:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"routinename"];

}
```

Currently they are adding fine to core data but I am unable to group them .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping in a table view is done via "sections" with these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)documentTableView
      //return number of routines

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)documentTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
      //return number of routine details for this routine

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)documentTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
      //return name of this routine
```

You have to think how you are going to handle "cancel". Right not you are inserting rows when the table cells are selected. Are you going to do a "rollback"? Alternatively you could keep track of selected rows in another array and do all the database work when "save" is tapped.

Lastly, your messageAlert is alloc'd but to released. It leaks.

Comment: I already have the cancel action sorted, just didn't want to clutter the question anymore. I was thinking about putting the selections in a n array but what I am really looking at is how to link the selected rows with the routine name the user enters.

Comment: i guess this could be achieved by letting all the actions being processed when the user clicks 'done' ?

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to have your objects grouped automatically when using the Sensible TableView framework. Check it out, should save you tons of time.